# How to search XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I looked at some threads but I think I'm missing something in Microsoft SQL Server (SSMS).

I have XML in column defined as `XML` datatype that looks like this:

(*I erased stuff before this not sure if it's needed*)

```
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="TEST" TransactionType="Insert">
    <ItemData ItemOID="TEACHER" Value="145"/>
    <ItemData ItemOID="AGE" Value="50" />
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="TEST" TransactionType="Insert">
    <ItemData ItemOID="TEACHER" Value="151"/>
    <ItemData ItemOID="AGE" Value="42" /> 
</ItemGroupData>
```

There's stuff I truncated but what is the most optimal way to locate the XML file where teacher 145 is and they can be in any of the Itemdata groups?

I can find it like:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(XML AS nvarchar(max)) AS test 
FROM
    table1 
WHERE
    XML LIKE '%14%'
```

but I am looking into learning different ways without casting unless that is the most optimal way?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that "stuff before" that you erased **will** be very important! You need to build up XPath expressions to select individual pieces from the XML - and those depend on **everything** from the root on down! Also - you might have **XML namespaces** that are defined in the "stuff before" - which you need to respect to get any results.

Anyhoo - *ASSUMING* you have just a `<root>....</root>` node before your XML, you could get your desired result like this :

```
DECLARE @XmlTbl TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @XmlTbl (ID, XmlData)
VALUES (1, 
    '<root><ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="TEST" TransactionType="Insert">
    <ItemData ItemOID="TEACHER" Value="145"/>
    <ItemData ItemOID="AGE" Value="50" />
</ItemGroupData>
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="TEST" TransactionType="Insert">
    <ItemData ItemOID="TEACHER" Value="151"/>
    <ItemData ItemOID="AGE" Value="42" /> 
</ItemGroupData></root>')

SELECT
    t.ID,
    XC.value('(@ItemGroupOID)', 'varchaR(50)') AS ItemGroupOID,
    XC.value('(@TransactionType)', 'varchaR(50)') AS TransactionType,
    XC2.value('@ItemOID', 'varchar(25)') AS ItemOID,
    XC2.value('@Value', 'int') AS value
FROM
    @XmlTbl t
CROSS APPLY    -- "enumerate" the <ItemGroupData> nodes under <root>
    XmlData.nodes('/root/ItemGroupData') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY    -- "enumerate" the <ItemData> subnodes
    XC.nodes('ItemData') AS XT2(XC2)
WHERE
    XC.value('(ItemData/@Value)[1]', 'int') = 145
```

This would return these results:

| ID | ItemGroupOID | TransactionType | ItemOID | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST | Insert | TEACHER | 145 |
| 1 | TEST | Insert | AGE | 50 |

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports powerful **XQuery** language to deal with the XML data type.

Please try the following solution.

It is using XPath predicate `[@Value=sql:variable("@TeacherValue")]` to search directly in the XML data type.

The `sql:variable("@TeacherValue")` construct allows to pass a parameter to it.

Also, SQL Server supports XML indexes for that.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XmlData XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (XmlData) VALUES
(N'<root>
    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="TEST" TransactionType="Insert">
        <ItemData ItemOID="TEACHER" Value="145"/>
        <ItemData ItemOID="AGE" Value="50"/>
    </ItemGroupData>
    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="TEST" TransactionType="Insert">
        <ItemData ItemOID="TEACHER" Value="151"/>
        <ItemData ItemOID="AGE" Value="42"/>
    </ItemGroupData>
</root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @TeacherValue INT = 145;

SELECT t.ID
    , p.value('@ItemGroupOID', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS ItemGroupOID
    , p.value('@TransactionType', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS TransactionType
    , c.value('@ItemOID', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS ItemOID
    , c.value('@Value', 'INT') AS value
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY XmlData.nodes('/root/ItemGroupData[ItemData[@ItemOID="TEACHER"
    and @Value=sql:variable("@TeacherValue")]]') AS t1(p)
CROSS APPLY t1.p.nodes('ItemData') AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | ItemGroupOID | TransactionType | ItemOID | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST | Insert | TEACHER | 145 |
| 1 | TEST | Insert | AGE | 50 |